# Generic path to read a file in a ROS directory

Tags: ros, python, cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a `/csv` and `/scripts` directories in my `/src` directory. The `/csv` directory contains a csv file and `/scripts` directory contains a Python script to parse the csv file. The first few lines of the script is as follows -

```
import csv
with open('/home//default_ws/src/<package_name>/csv/alarms.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
```

How can I add a generic location path for the csv file in my Python script? And what modifications do I need to make in my `CMakelists.txt` in order to install the `/csv` and `/scripts` directories?

*** CORRECT ANSWER ***

```
import csv
import os, rospkg
rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
with open(os.path.join(rospack.get_path("package_name"), "csv", "alarms.csv"), 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274242/generic-path-to-read-a-file-in-a-ros-directory/) by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get path of your package you can use `rospack` package. Take a look at examples [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Packages#Client_Library_Support).

This is basically it:

```
import rospkg 
rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
# get the file path for rospy_tutorials
rospack.get_path('rospy_tutorials')
```

In order to install your scripts you need to use cmake's [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html).

For example like this:

```
install(PROGRAMS
  "scripts/my_script"
  DESTINATION bin
)
```

Then it depends on if you're using catkin_make or catkin build command. To install the script you run `catkin_make install`. Or if you're using catkin build you need to config your package with catkin `config config --install` and then run `catkin build`.

This should install your script to install directory of your root's workspace.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on 2017-10-27**:
How should I modify `with open('/home//default_ws/src/<package_name>/csv/alarms.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:` in my code?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-27**:
I'm not familiar with python. But I would probably save output of `rospack.get_path('your_package')` to some variable. Then somehow add the last part of your path (`csv/alarms.csv`) and insert it to `open()`. But this is already python related.

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-27**:
You should just be able to concatenate strings by adding them:

```
with open(rospack.get_path('<package_name>')+'/csv/alarms.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
If I may suggest: *always* use `os.path.join(..)` instead of concatenating path segments with hard-coded path delimiters (ie: `/`). You never know where your code ends up.

**Comment by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on 2017-10-27**:
It works! Thank you @gvdhoorn

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
If @l4ncelot's suggestion of using `rospack` for this worked, then I believe it would be good if you could mark his answer as *the* answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of it. It should turn green.